# How can i split margin for bottomnavigationbar items in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my bottomnavigationbar like the image i attached, but i just do not seem to get it.
below is what i've tried.

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.amber,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(200), topRight: Radius.circular(200)),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          iconSize: 0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Banking',
                icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Social', icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'GTLocate',
                icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'iReport',
                icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'GTTraffic',
                icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.accessibleIcon)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

this is what i want to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8bWU.jpg)

this is what i have currently
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP7zU.jpg)

Comment: Can you try wrapping your ```FaIcon```'s in ```Container```, and adding ```margin``` to the ```Container```?

Comment: @Andrej It's doesn't accept container in Bottomnavigationbaritem

Comment: No, not the `BottomNavigationBarItem`, but it's icon paramter. Like this: `BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Container(child: YourIcon(),),`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only left border of background color for all the items except the first one in the bottom nav bar to achieve the result. I made a custom bottom navigation bar close to the design you provided:

Check this: [ImageNavBar - Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/181dcfd70b9269ccdc9cf0c5e8693907)

Adjust the height, image and color according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much.. perfect

Comment: There were some minor issues in the code I posted since I changed it to Animated Container at the last moment. I have updated the code. You can refer to the link again if you get any errors using the previous code for the widget.